# Move 'Reset North' button on Android studio for mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I was wondering if there was a way to move the location of the 'Reset North' button that is generated by Mapbox. It is in the top right of the screen where my `EditText` (search) is, so my `EditText` blocks it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the placement of the compass with:

```
mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: Crashed 'on a null object reference' @Tobrun

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032179/remove-or-move-reset-north-button-on-android-studio-for-mapbox/55935120#55935120

Comment: @MatthewMitchell Sorry for being very meta and posting a link to your own question, but it's just to help others having the same problem.