# Remove or move 'Reset North' button on Android studio for Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

I was wondering if there was a way to move the location of the 'Reset North' button that is generated by Mapbox. It is in the top right of the screen where my EditText (search) is, so my EditText blocks it. Other option is adding a custom "Reset North" button, but I would still need to move or remove the original function.

I have tired `mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassMargins(left, top, right, bottom);`

but the app crashes Error:

```
'on a null object reference'
```

Link to previous question, no one is replying to that. [Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832100/move-reset-north-button-on-android-studio-for-mapbox)

Comment: This helped me so much, I was coding on a Huawei p8 lite, which are notorious for bad logging when it comes to errors, and could not figure out why the code was crashing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error until I realized that I was putting the padding or compass margins in my onCreate(Bundle) and not my onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap).

Therefore in your onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap) you can put the following code at the end of the method:

```
MainActivity.this.mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Alternatively you can use this, if you want to set the padding around all components in the MapboxMap:

```
MainActivity.this.mapboxMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```